# Parsing a String in SSIS or C#

Tags: regex

I have one string without any delimiter and I want to parse it. Is it possible in SSIS or c#. 
For Example, If I have address info in a single column, but i want to split/parse it in multiple columns such as House Number, Road Number, Road name, Road type, Locality name, state code, post code, country wise etc. 
12/38 Meacher Street Mount Druitt NSW 2770 Australia -- In this case House Number:- 12, road no:- 38, road name meacher, road type - road, locality :- mount druitt, state-NSW, post code:- 2770

have all these info in a single column, so how I will parse it and split inh multiple columns. I know by giving space delimiter will not work as there will be split the wrong information and there will be some road name with more than space , so in this info will be split up in wrong column. 
Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: How about using tuple ?   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Good luck since that data is all together...

Comment: If you don't want a solution in VB.Net, why is it tagged?

Answer (score 0):

Please remember that the country can also have spaces in it and some countries use alphanumerical post codes.

If all addresses are in Australia and in the same format of (...), state, postcode, Australia then you can split it into 
StreetAddress, State, PostCode

You could also use one of online APIs to find an address and then then you get individual elements.

The best solution is to keep it together - why split it?